# Is the main character (Kal-el) of The Pilot's Love Song related to Superman?

Tags: the-pilots-love-song

The main character of *Toaru Hikuushi e no Koiuta* is named Kal-el. This immediately made me think of Clark Kent's birth name of Kal-el from *Superman*. Is there any relationship between this work and *Superman*?

Comment: Huh. I'm pretty familiar with the Superman canon prior to the last 10 years, and nothing in the first episode struck me as having anything to do with any Superman stories I'm aware of. A brief search doesn't reveal anyone on the Japanese internet drawing connections between this and Superman, either. I wouldn't chalk this up to coincidence, though - if you're going to name your character something as unusual yet precedented as "Kal-el", you presumably have a good reason for doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. His name is a portmanteau of his real first and last name, カール (kaaru) and イール (iiru), respectively. In actuality, he is the first Prince of a certain Empire...